# Blotchy Water based Poly

Tags: polyurethane

Got new unfinished dark walnut cabinets. Used water based poly after a thorough light sanding and cleaning. After two coats the cabinets look blotchy. What can i do? Thinking about sanding them down and starting over. Please help

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE! Pictures would help a lot here so we can see what's going on exactly. Is the blotchy effect one of finish or colour or both? Can it be seen from all angles or mostly from the side and not straight on etc? Depending on what the issue is it's possible you just need to apply more of the poly to even up the finish — although it's not common on walnut sometimes wood is more absorbent in some areas than others, and the parts where it drinks in the finish look more matt than the areas where it hasn't been absorbed as much (possibly due to using a poly more watery than average).

Answer (score 1):

I got decent results with water based poly by lightly sanding with 400 between coats and applying like 6 or 9 of them. Then I used steel wool of highest grade (#0000?) to get it to uniform matte sheen on the last coat (and to get rid of all the bubbles). Then after a few weeks I used random orbital sander with wool pad and plastic polishing compound to get it to gloss. (I used NOVUS Plastic Polish, but I'm sure there are others).

Use several thin coats of poly with light sanding between coats. First couple of coats always look like crap. After that wood is sealed and it starts to get much easier (unless you use too much poly at once, then you get different kinds of problems).

Use steel wool only on the last coat (to avoid rusting strands embedded under the layers). Very high grade sandpaper might also work, but using steel wool it is easier to bring uneven surfaces to uniform sheen and to hide any imperfections in the finish.

Wait a few days before using steel wool and wait a few weeks (check instructions on the can, usually a month I think) before trying to polish.

Comment: *"and to get rid of all the bubbles"* you're doing something wrong if there are that many :-)

Comment: @Graphus, Heh, not _too_ many :), but even one bubble turns perfectly uniform sheen into blotched mess after it is removed. So I usually have to go steel wool and plastic polish over all surface anyway...

Comment: Yeah just one bubble spoils the party if you're after a pristine finish. The problem with bubbles is one of the reasons I'm not a big fan of waterbased poly and other WB finishes, although their colour definitely has its uses.